# How to disable default route on controller ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a web application (ASP.NET MVC 5) with a custom **admin** section where all the parameters of the apps are.

I want to be able to easily change the name of this section.

E.g.

```
myapp.com/admin/{controller}/{action}
```

could be

```
myapp.com/custom-admin-name/{controller}/{action}
```

I've tried to use areas but it seems like it would be hard to edit their name since all the `controllers` and `models` are bound to the area's `namespace`.

I've also tried to set custom routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminControllerAction",
    "custom-admin-name/{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" }
);
```

So I could do

```
mywebsite.com/custom-admin-name/dashboard/index
```

But the problem with that is that my **admin controllers and actions are still callable** using

```
mywebsite.com/dashboard/index
```

Is it possible to cancel the default routing of a controller/action ?

Is there any more viable solutions to this problem that I wouldn't have thought about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to restrict the controller namespaces for a given route, so controllers which don't belong to those namespaces will be ignored.

For example, the following will be restricted to controllers in the namespace `YourApp.Controllers` (You can add multiple namespaces if needed):

```
Route route = routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "YourApp.Controllers" }                
);
route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

Disabling the namespace fallback is important, otherwise you will just be prioritizing those namespaces.

So, you could restrict the default route to the namespace `YourApp.Controllers` as above and create a custom admin route restricted to the namespace `YourApp.Controllers.Admin`:

```
Route route = routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminControllerAction",
    "custom-admin-name/{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "YourApp.Controllers.Admin" }                
);
route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

Please note that as mentioned by Tareck, the admin route has to be defined before the general route.

Comment: I'm going to test tonight it but it seems like a viable solution

Comment: I would add that, to make it work, you need to put the admin routes section before the default one

Answer (score 1):

Try removing with this

```
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["NAME ROUTE YOU WISH TO RMOVE"]);
```